# issues with perlbrew and perl cgi shebang

Tags: perl, cgi, perlbrew

How do I properly set the shibang for perlbrew environment for CGI as apache will not load any env details?

I could use -I, however, how do i list multiple libraries as there is 2.

```
#!/home/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.10.1/bin/perl -wTI /home/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib
```

Thats how I can get one, how do I add a second library, and even if I did will this work?

Comment: More `-I` options. But if you're editing the script file to begin with, why not just add some `use lib` lines?

Comment: I ended up doing it in the shabang, its nasty for now, but basically #!/home/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.10.1/bin/perl -wTI /home/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/5.10.1 /home/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/site_perl/5.10.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it in the shabang:

```
#!/home/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.10.1/bin/perl -wTI /home/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/5.10.1 /home/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.10.1/lib/site_perl/5.10.1
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use `-I` more than once.
2. I'd use `use lib "path", "path";` instead of placing `-I` in the shebang line.
3. `$install_dir/lib` shouldn't contain any modules. They should be in one of the following, all of which are already in the `@INC` for `$install_dir/bin/perl`.

   - `$install_dir/lib/5.10.1` (Core modules with no build-specific components)
   - `$install_dir/lib/5.10.1/$arch` (Core modules with build-specific components)
   - `$install_dir/lib/site_perl/5.10.1` (User-installed modules with no build-specific components)
   - `$install_dir/lib/site_perl/5.10.1/$arch` (User-installed modules with build-specific components)